# setInterval not clearing on onTouchStart event for autoplay, infinite carousel react comp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, carousel

I want to stop setInterval function on onTouchStart event and start the same function after 3000 ms on onTouchEnd event for swipe function.

I have created simple carousel with auto play , infinite scrolling, with swipe function.
I want to stop setInterval function on onTouchStart event and start after 3000 ms on onTouchEnd event.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './Carousel.scss';

const Carousel = ({ assetsData }) => {
    const containerRef = useRef(null);
    const slideRef = useRef(null);

    const Data = [...assetsData];

    const [CalcWidth, setCalcWidth] = useState(0);
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const interval = 3000;

    let touchStartX = 0;
    let touchEndX = 0;
    const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide-img');

    useEffect(() => {
        const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        const calculatedWidth = Number(windowWidth) - 32;
        setCalcWidth(calculatedWidth);
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
            '--calculated-width',
            `${calculatedWidth / 16}rem`
        );
    }, []);
    let autoplayInterval;

    useEffect(() => {
        autoplayInterval = setInterval(() => {
            nextSlide();
        }, interval);
        return () => clearInterval(autoplayInterval);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        showSlide(index);
    }, [index]);

    function showSlide(index) {
        const slideWidth = slides[0].clientWidth;
        if (slideRef.current) {
            slideRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${
                -slideWidth * index - index * 8
            }px)`;
            slideRef.current.style.transition = '0.7s ease-out';
        }
    }

    function nextSlide() {
        setIndex((prevIndex) => {
            if (prevIndex < slides.length - 1) {
                return prevIndex + 1;
            } else {
                if (slideRef.current) {
                    slideRef.current.style.transition = 'none';
                    slideRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${0}px)`;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }

    function prevSlide() {
        setIndex((prevIndex) => {
            if (prevIndex > 0) {
                return prevIndex - 1;
            } else if (index === 0) {
                let tempIndex = slides.length - 1;
                let lastImageXvalue = CalcWidth * tempIndex + tempIndex * 8;
                if (slideRef.current) {
                    slideRef.current.style.transition = 'none';
                    slideRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${-lastImageXvalue}px)`;
                }
                return slides.length - 1;
            }
        });
    }

    function handleSwipeStart(event) {
        touchStartX = event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX;
        clearInterval(autoplayInterval);
    }

    function handleSwipeEnd(event) {
        touchEndX = event.clientX || event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
        const deltaX = touchStartX - touchEndX;
        if (deltaX > 0) {
            nextSlide();
        } else if (deltaX < 0) {
            prevSlide();
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            autoplayInterval = setInterval(() => {
                nextSlide();
            }, interval);
        }, interval);
    }

    return (
        <div className='container' ref={containerRef}>
            <div
                className='slides'
                ref={slideRef}
                onTouchStart={handleSwipeStart}
                onTouchEnd={handleSwipeEnd}
            >
                {Data.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment key={index}>
                            <div className='slide-img'>
                            <img src={item.url} alt={item.alt} />
                            </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Carousel;
```